# Adding members to private groups using api requests in slack

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-bot

I wanted to invite a member into a private channel in slack automatically using slack API.
i use the method https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.invite. i gave app for the api toekn and configured the bot and user permiision with group. write and group.write.invite and channel.write.invite etc as mentioned in the  documentation . I used the bot token to send the api request but the response i received was scope not provided requested scope: group.write and group.write.invite which i had already provided.
I tried reinstaling the app still the problem repeats.
What should i do
[API Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMYN0.png)

I am expecting the member in my workspace to be added to the private channel